# pandas: appending a row to a dataframe with values derived using a user defined formula applied on selected columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I can use the following to achieve the traditional calculation like `mean()`, `sum()`etc.

```
df.loc['calc'] = df[['A','D']].iloc[2:4].mean(axis=0)
```

Now I have two questions

1. How can I `apply` a formula (like `exp(mean())` or `2.5*mean()/sqrt(max())` to column 'A' and 'D' for rows 2 to 4
2. How can I append row to the existing `df` where two values would be `mean()` of the `A` and `D` and two values would be of specific formula result of `C` and `B`.

Comment: it is better show us what is your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:**

You can use `.apply()` and `lambda` functions.

```
df.iloc[2:4,[0,3]].apply(lambda x: np.exp(np.mean(x)))
df.iloc[2:4,[0,3]].apply(lambda x: 2.5*np.mean(x)/np.sqrt(max(x)))
```

**Q2:**

You can use dictionaries and combine them and add it as a row. 
First one is mean, the second one is some custom function.

```
ad = dict(df[['A', 'D']].mean())
bc = dict(df[['B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x.sum()*45))
```

*Combine them*:

```
ad.update(bc)

df = df.append(ad, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: the thing which you have suggested, can it be possible to do the same in `Spark 1.6.3`

Comment: I imagine you could